# Regex for finding alternate duplicate characters

Tags: regex

I have the following data list

```
10000
12100
12312
12120
```

I'm writing a regex to find the alternate duplicate count. So the above list will give

```
2 -> (two zeros)
1 -> (1 in 121)
0 -> (no alternate duplicate)
2 -> (1 in 121 and 2 in 212)
```

I have written the following regex

```
([0-9])(?!\1)([0-9])(?:\1\2)*\1
```

This does not work for 1st and last set. In first set, it is not working when there are the same digit in the between like `111`. In last it set it is not working for `212`.

check: https://regexr.com/5674s

Comment: Try `([0-9])(?=[0-9]\1)`  https://regex101.com/r/yhsU53/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the negative lookahead `(?!\1)` the group will capture the first zero in the example `10000`, but there are only zeroes at the right side so there will be no match as the backreference contains a zero.

You might capture a digit in group 1, and assert what is directly on the right is a digit followed by group 1.

```
([0-9])(?=[0-9]\1)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yhsU53/1/)